# Bootstrap - Remove gap between columns within a row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page that is dynamically adding columns to a row from a database result.

There is a single parent row wrapper and multiple columns within that row. I expect them to take up the full width of the parent an align accordingly but there appears to be a gap as some of the sections grow in height.

How can I have these panels fit together without being pushed down?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o483edpt/

[image]

Here is a snippet of code for this section:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Section -->
                <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let s of profileData.sections.section">
                    <div class="hpanel hblue">
                        <div class="panel-heading hbuilt">
                            <i class="{{ s.Icon }} padRight"></i>{{ s.SectionName }}
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-external-link pull-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped" *ngIf="s.fields">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr *ngFor="let f of s.fields.field">
                                        <td>{{ f.FieldTitle }}</td>
                                        <td>{{ f.Value }}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div *ngIf="!s.fields">
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    No Data Available
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Section -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: so you are trying to get your child elements take full width as parent element ?

Comment: @JismonThomas - I have a single row with many `col-md-6` divs in them. I figured once they take up the full width, it would knock the next one down below (which its doing). However, once it goes below, its creating a gap and not just putting it directly below .. Does that make sense?

Comment: -Am not sure if I clearly understood you, I tried your code with the class col-md-12 instead of col-md-6, everything seems to be working fine, is it possible that you can post the code where your sections has gap issue ?

Comment: Hmm, the fiddle should shown the same issue I am facing - http://jsfiddle.net/o483edpt/

I want to two columns as it is (6/6) but I need them to fit together, masonry style I guess you could call it.

Comment: I don't think that you can do that with the current structure since bootstrap row will add everything on horizontal direction and you have variable contents, unless you split your row into two 6 columns and add content separately to them